# Hex-literals, compiler error or badly written spec?

Tags: scala, overflow

Scala spec says

> #### 1.3.1 Integer Literals
>
> Syntax:
>
> ```
> integerLiteral ::= (decimalNumeral | hexNumeral | octalNumeral) [‘L’ | ‘l’]
> decimalNumeral ::= ‘0’ | nonZeroDigit {digit}
> hexNumeral     ::= ‘0’ ‘x’ hexDigit {hexDigit}
> octalNumeral   ::= ‘0’ octalDigit {octalDigit}
> digit          ::= ‘0’ | nonZeroDigit
> nonZeroDigit   ::= ‘1’ | · · · | ‘9’
> octalDigit     ::= ‘0’ | · · · | ‘7’
> ```
>
> Integer literals are usually of type Int, or of type Long when followed by a `L` or `l`
>   suffix. Values of type Int are all integer numbers between -2<sup>31</sup> and 2<sup>31</sup>-1, inclusive. Values of type Long are all integer numbers between -2<sup>63</sup> and 2<sup>63</sup>-1, inclusive.
>   A compile-time error occurs if an integer literal denotes a number outside these
>   ranges

Last time I checked `0x80000000` equals 2147483648 which should be out of range for an `Int` (*"between -2<sup>31</sup> and 2<sup>31</sup>-1, inclusive"*).

Still the compiler does *not* complain but instead lets the integer overflow into -2147483648.

So, is the spec wrong, is the compiler wrong, or have I misunderstood anything?

**Edit:** The same number, written in decimal form is treated correctly and produces an error.

Comment: FWIW, Scala's behavior in this regard is identical to Java.

Answer (score 3):

The most significant bit in a signed integer is used to indicate the sign, and not a high power of 2 - thus anything with this bit set will represent a negative, and not a positive, number. The [two's complement](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement) form is used, meaning that 0x8000000 does indeed equal -2147483648.

To your edit: the same number written in decimal is -2147483638, not +2147483638, for the same reason.

Comment: *"The most significant bit in a signed integer is used to indicate the sign"*. Well, that obviously depends on which base you type the number in. The literal "2147483648" (which as I see it represents the same number), does *not* follow your logic.

Comment: No, the binary base is implicit in my choice of the word "bit" rather than "digit".

Comment: @DavidM He meant that it only works that way if you write the number in base 16, not in base 10. If you write a number in base 10 whose sign bit would be a set that results in an error instead of a negative number (which is what the spec says should happen).

Comment: @sepp2k, exactly. My question could be rephrased as follows: Spec doesn't say that an integer literal should be treated differently depending on which base it is written in, still 0x80000000 is treated differently from 2147483648.

Comment: @aioobe - with that rephrasing, I think I'd agree that the spec is not sufficiently descriptive. I have always thought of a hex number as being the hex representation of the internal bit state (hence binary) of the number, rather than an integer literal in base 16. In the latter interpretation, yes, you're right, the integer literals in different bases are treated differently. But I think you'll find that when specifying a 32 bit hex value, this is directly translated into its binary equivalent by the compiler, generating the switch in sign.

Answer (score 2):

As pointed out by [dave](https://stackoverflow.com/users/115478/dave), "*Scala's behavior in this regard is identical to Java.*"

Which leads me to believe that Scala have chosen Java's interpretation regarding integer literals all together.

This behaviour is covered quite well in the Java Language Specification, [Section 3.10.1 Integer Literals](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/lexical.html#3.10.1):

> The largest positive hexadecimal and octal literals of type `int` are `0x7fffffff` and `017777777777`, respectively, which equal `2147483647` (2<sup>31</sup>-1). The most negative hexadecimal and octal literals of type `int` are `0x80000000` and `020000000000`, respectively, each of which represents the decimal value -2147483648 (-2<sup>31</sup>). The hexadecimal and octal literals `0xffffffff` and `037777777777`, respectively, represent the decimal value -1.

All in all, I'd say the spec is **implicitly inheriting Java's spec** for parts that are equal and sort of obvious, and is only explicit on the parts that (may) differ, for instance syntax (the language is after all syntactically quite different from Java).

Answer (score 1):

Unsigned numbers *in hexadecimal form* from 2<sup>31</sup> and 2<sup>32</sup>-1 are silently converted into negative numbers corresponding to their binary representation, for `Int`. Negative numbers in that range (except -2<sup>31</sup>) are silently converted into their complement-2, which wraps into positive numbers. An equivalent rule applies for `Long`. IMHO, the spec should say so, but I didn't check to see if it does or not.

The compiler does complain about numbers outside this range.

Comment: *Unsigned numbers from 2^31 and 2^32-1 are silently converted into negative numbers* -- Hmm. I get `integer number too large 2147483649`. (And 2147483649 is an unsigned number in that range.)